# How to find from which view controller a method is called

Tags: ios, facebook, storyboard, viewcontroller, uiview-hierarchy

To give more specifics: I am working with FBLoginView.
I am using storyboards and a separate xib file for my LoginViewController.
In my app, I have a loginViewController which is a FBLoginViewDelegate.
And a SettingsViewController which is a FBUserSettingsDelegate.
And I have a skip button in my loginView in order to sign in as a guest instead of a facebook user.

Now what I am doing is:
When the app opens, I show a Walkthrough view which includes the login view at the bottom. 
When the user logs in with Facebook login button, the following method gets executed automatically via facebook sdk:

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                        user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user;
```

in this method i am performing a segue to main view.

However people can also choose to first login as a guest, and then go to Settings, and they can still login to facebook. Which happens to execute the same method above!

But then my segue isn't recognized because I am not in the Walkthrough viewcontroller anymore. Now I am in settings view controller which is in a totally different place in the hierarchy in my storyboard.

So my question is:
How can I know from which viewcontroller this method is being invoked?

I am getting this warning:
 Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Thank you for all your helps.

Comment: In short: I want the method to behave differently when the user logs in from different places in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyAppDelegate *tmpDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
id myCurrentController = tmpDelegate.myNavigationController.topViewController;
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass(myCurrentController.class));
```

Hope this helps..

Have a try on this:

```
+ (UIViewController*) topMostController
{
    UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

    while (topController.presentedViewController) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController;
    }

    return topController;
}
```

Comment: i don't have a navigation controller?

Comment: or let's say it is more complicated: storyboard starts with a normal view controller. then moves on to a SWRevealViewController (you can google it) and then, it goes to one main view controller which is embedded in a navigation, and the other buttons on the side menu go to normal view controllers

Comment: super thanks. i can now get where the call to the same delegate method comes from!